# Who was District 12's First Victor?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the first book it mentions that Haymitch was the *second-ever victor* from District 12.

**Who was the first victor? What do we know about them?**

Comment: Does it ever actually say that he was the *second* victor?

Comment: @Alex https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47071206#47071206

Comment: An unknown female See here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196168/where-in-the-books-does-it-say-the-first-victor-of-district-12-was-female

Answer (score 5):

[Lucy Gray Baird](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Lucy_Gray_Baird) won the 10th Hunger Games, as outlined in *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*.

"What do we know about them" is a pretty broad question, and generally reading the prequel book would be the best way to answer it. We know that she was Covey, a group that migrated across Panem before the war, but ended up in District 12. She has no living family, and works as a musician (guitar and vocals). She had no particular expertise with any weapon or fighting technique, and won mostly through the support of her mentor.

The 10th Games were seen as somewhat of a disaster, with nearly all recordings destroyed. At the time the Games were not widely viewed outside the Capitol, so most knowledge of Lucy Gray and the 10th Games has been lost.

Answer (score 3):

#### In the original trilogy: all that is known is that the only other District 12 victor is dead.

The only thing ever mentioned about the past victor from District 12 in the original trilogy is that they are dead.

> “Then he reads the list of past District 12 victors. In seventy-four years, we have had exactly two. Only one is still alive.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Hunger Games (Chapter 1)*</sup></sub>

After this, District 12’s previous victor is never mentioned in the trilogy again.

#### In the prequel book, Lucy Gray Baird is a victor from District 12, but her Games were erased from history by the Capitol, so she is likely *not* the one who is listed with Haymitch.

The prequel book to the Hunger Games trilogy, The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes, focuses on the 10th Hunger Games, which is won by a girl from District 12, Lucy Gray Baird.

> “Just the opposite of your girl, Lucy Gray. Sixteen going on thirty-five, and a hard thirty-five at that,” observed Dean Highbottom.
>
> “She gave you the compact?” Coriolanus’s heart dropped at the thought.
>
> “Oh, don’t blame her. The Peacekeepers had to wrestle her to the ground to get the thing. Naturally, we do a thorough search of the victors when they leave the arena.” The dean cocked his head and smiled. “So smart about how she poisoned Wovey and Reaper. Not really fair play, but what’s to be done? Sending her back to District Twelve seems punishment enough. She said the rat poison was all her idea, that the compact had just been a token.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes (Chapter 21)*</sup></sub>

However, Lucy Gray Baird is not necessarily the dead victor of District 12 referenced in the first Hunger Games book, since the Capitol planned to erase her Games from history because it made them look too vulnerable. They erased the tapes of her Games and never aired it again. At that time, the Hunger Games were not very popular, so she would be forgotten, and there likely would be no memory of her by the time of the 74th Hunger Games.

> “You erased it?” he asked.
>
> “Every last copy gone, never to be aired again.” She grinned. “I’ve a master in the vault, of course, but that’s just for my own amusement.”
>
> He was glad about the erasure. It was just one more way to eliminate Lucy Gray from the world. The Capitol would forget her, the districts barely knew her, and District 12 had never accepted her as one of their own. In a few years, there would be a vague memory that a girl had once sung in the arena. And then that would be forgotten, too. Good-bye, Lucy Gray, we hardly knew you.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes (Chapter 30)*</sup></sub>

Though she was their victor, watching the Hunger Games was not mandatory at that point, and no one in District 12 did, so the people of 12 would not have remembered her and passed along the story of her around the district.

> “It’s all pointless, though, you know. The Hunger Games. No one in Twelve even watches it. Except for the reaping. We didn’t even have a working television on base.”
>
> “While that could be a problem in the future, it’s a blessing this year, given that I’ve had to erase the whole mess,” said Dr. Gaul. “It was a mistake getting the students mixed up in it. Especially when they started dropping like flies. Presented the Capitol as far too vulnerable.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes (Chapter 30)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, the reaping is an event held by the Capitol, so it is unlikely they would let someone from a Hunger Games they erased be included on the list of previous victors, so it is more likely that the victor from District 12 who is read on the list with Haymitch is actually *not* Lucy Gray Baird, but someone else.