# Does music exist in Panem? And if so, what kinds of music?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Does music exist in the *The Hunger Games* universe? And if so, what kinds of music?

Rap, Electronic, Rock, Classical, Jazz, Street performers, etc?

**Does music exist in Panem?**

Comment: Seeing as this world is not our own world as we know it (far future dystopia), any genres that we would think of would not be inherently applicable aside from "folk", "big band", and "orchestral" as they are basic genre types. That said, you should accept Alex's answer as the correct answer with the little green check mark next to the upvote/downvote selector.

Answer (score 25):

There is quite a bit of music interspersed throughout the series:

In Chapter Five of *The Hunger Games* there is music during the chariot procession:

> The opening music begins. It’s easy to hear, blasted around
>   the Capitol.

In Chapter Ten there is music when they go on the roof the night before the Games start:

> The roof is not lit at night, but as soon as my bare feel reach
>   its tiled surface I see his silhouette, black against the lights
>   that shine endlessly in the Capitol. There’s quite a commotion
>   going on down in the streets, music and singing and car horns,
>   none of which I could hear through the thick glass window
>   panels in my room.

In Chapter Eleven there is music when the casualties for the day are shown:

> That’s it. The Capitol seal is
>   back with a final musical flourish. Then darkness and the
>   sounds of the forest resume.

In Chapter Sixteen Rue and Katniss talk about music, but it turns out that they're apparently talking about singing and not actual instrumental music:

> Rue, who when you ask her what she loves
>   most in the world, replies, of all things, “Music.”
>
> “Music?” I say. In our world, I rank music somewhere between hair ribbons and rainbows in terms of usefulness. At
>   least a rainbow gives you a tip about the weather. “You have a
>   lot of time for that?”
>
> “We sing at home. At work, too. That’s why I love your pin,”
>   she says, pointing to the mockingjay that I’ve again forgotten
>   about.
>
> “You have mockingjays?” I ask.
>
> “Oh, yes. I have a few that are my special friends. We can
>   sing back and forth for hours. They carry messages for me,”
>   she says.

In Chapter Eighteen when Rue dies she asks Katniss to sing for her (which Katniss does) and Katniss reminisces about the music of her father singing:

> “Sing,” she says, but I barely catch the word.
>
> Sing? I think. Sing what? I do know a few songs. Believe it or
>   not, there was once music in my house, too. Music I helped
>   make. My father pulled me in with that remarkable voice —
>   but I haven’t sung much since he died. Except when Prim is
>   very sick. Then I sing her the same songs she liked as a baby.

We also see in that scene that Katniss actually had a music teacher:

> What my music
>   teacher calls a mountain air.

In Chapter Twenty-Two we find out that they actually had music assemblies in school:

> “So that day, in music assembly, the teacher asked who
>   knew the valley song. Your hand shot right up in the air. She
>   stood you up on a stool and had you sing it for us. And I swear,
>   every bird outside the windows fell silent,” Peeta says.

In Chapter Five of *Catching Fire* musicians play during the tour of District 11:

> Somewhere below, musicians begin to play. As the first wave of our little procession
>   begins down the steps, Peeta and I join hands.

In Chapter Six musicians play at the party in President Snow's mansion:

> About halfway between the floor and the
>   ceiling, musicians float on what look like fluffy white clouds, but I can't see what holds them
>   aloft.

Later at the party we find out that in District 12 they presumably had fiddle and flute music:

> Music filters down from the clouds as he leads me away from the team, the table, and out
>   onto the floor. We know only a few dances at home, the kind that go with fiddle and flute
>   music and require a good deal of space. But Effie has shown us some that are popular in the Capitol.

In Chapter Twelve we find out that there is an electronic gadget called a music chip:

> I begin to question them casually about what other hardships this winter has brought them.
>   They are not used to want, so any little disruption in supply makes an impact on them. By the
>   time I'm ready to be dressed, their complaints about the difficulty of getting different
>   products — from crabmeat to music chips to ribbons — has given me a sense of which
>   districts might actually be rebelling. Seafood from District 4. Electronic gadgets from District
>   3. And, of course, fabrics from District 8. The thought of such widespread rebellion has me
>   quivering with fear and excitement.

In Chapter Sixteen we get more information about what a music chip is:

> “The strength of the thread,” Beetee finishes explaining. “Automatically. It rules out
>   human error.” Then he talks about his recent success creating a musical chip that's tiny
>   enough to be concealed in a flake of glitter but can hold hours of songs. I remember Octavia
>   talking about this during the wedding shoot, and I see a possible chance to allude to the
>   uprising.

In Chapter Two of *Mockingjay* music plays on television after Peeta's interview:

> Music plays them out, and then there's a woman reading a list of expected shortages in the Capitol — fresh
>   fruit, solar batteries, soap.

In Chapter Sixteen there is music at Finninck's wedding:

> The three hundred lucky guests culled from 13 and the many refugees wear their
>   everyday clothes, the decorations are made from autumn foliage, the music is provided by a choir of children
>   accompanied by the lone fiddler who made it out of 12 with his instrument.

This also tells us that there were multiple musicians back in District 12.

Comment: You researched this too much. :-p Well done!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. [The Hunger Games Wiki](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Songs) has the following three:

#### [Deep In The Meadow](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Songs#%22Deep%20In%20The%20Meadow%22)

> "Deep In The Meadow" (also known as "Rue's Lullaby") is a song that is sung by Katniss to Rue, who was on her deathbed after Marvel speared her in the stomach. Rue's last request was to hear Katniss sing

#### [The Hanging Tree](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Songs#%22The%20Hanging%20Tree%22)

> This song was taught to Katniss Everdeen by her father, Mr. Everdeen, when she was young. Her mother, Mrs. Everdeen heard her singing the song and watched Prim and her making necklaces of rope to go with it.

#### [The Valley Song](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Songs#%22The%20Valley%20Song%22)

> The Valley Song is mentioned in the first Hunger Games book by Peeta in the caves, saying how he remembers Katniss singing this song at school.

All three of the songs are folk songs as befits people who lack the resources to make musical instruments.  It is safe to assume that the Capital has its own music but Katniss never has much opportunity to experience it.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by *not citing the Hunger Games Wikia*, [the most ridiculously unreliable Wikia I've come across](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/196207/31394).

Comment: My answer was more relevant to the question as originally phrased.

Comment: As originally phrased? There've been no changes to the question except a bit of formatting.

Comment: I seem to recall it started out saying "Hunger Games" not "Panem".

Comment: Same difference, no? I don't see how that distinction makes citing the unreliable HG Wikia more or less useful.

Comment: Hey, don't forget the comments are not for extended discussion. That said, it does not matter how reliable a Wiki is or is not. If the information is accurate, which in this case it is, then it does not matter where it comes from as the actual source material is still the books. Also "Hunger Games" can be taken to refer to the first novel. "Panem" implies the world of the novels.